# Greatest Function in Netezza

Tags: sql, netezza

Am trying to find the equivalent statement to below in Netezza

```
greatest(table1.column1, table2.column2, table3.column3)
```

also

```
least(table1.column1, table2.column2, table3.column3)
```

all the columns are dates

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

In newer versions of Netezza, this will also work:

```
max(table1.column1, table2.column2, table3.column3)
min(table1.column1, table2.column2, table3.column3)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `CASE WHEN` expression to duplicate the `greatest` function logic:

```
CASE WHEN table1.column1 > table2.column2
     THEN CASE WHEN table1.column1 > table3.column3 
               THEN table1.column1 
               ELSE table3.column3
          END
     ELSE CASE WHEN table2.column2 > table3.column3 
               THEN table2.column2
               ELSE table3.column3
          END
END
```

The same can be done for the `least` function.

Answer (score 1):

The [Netezza SQL Extensions toolkit](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSULQD_7.1.0/com.ibm.nz.sqltk.doc/c_sqlext_install_and_setup.html?cp=SSULQD_7.1.0%2F10) includes a `greatest` and a `least` function that take a variable number of arguments.